# Trying to install APLS on Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, gdal, fiona

So basically i'm trying to install Apls from this repo: https://github.com/CosmiQ/apls
However, I keep running into issue with GDAL and Fiona.

First, I tried to install it on my local machine (Windows_10_x64), by creating a visual environment in Pycharm and install bit by bit, everything worked fine, I even successfully installed GDAL 2.4.0 - until I try to install Fiona, it said it require Visual Studio 14 (which i did have on my computer - and i have checked the environment variables).

Then, I try to install APLS on a linux system, so i used google colab. Currently, my code looked like this:

```
!apt-get update
!apt-get install python3.6
!apt-get install python3.6-dev
!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.6 get-pip.py

import sys
sys.path[2] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[7] ='/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'

!python3.6 -m pip install apls==0.1.0
```

And it keep giving me this error:

```
Collecting GDAL==2.4.0
  Downloading GDAL-2.4.0.tar.gz (564 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 564 kB 49.8 MB/s            
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/b0/a2ecb10a68a319910c4681f452c83843b99c4ef6231d33a8e55b0104a50c/GDAL-2.4.0.tar.gz#sha256=b725a580e6faa0bc17edc3e6caa1da9e6efc401fab19e8482631ee179132b4df (from https://pypi.org/simple/gdal/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GDAL==2.4.0 (from apls) (from versions: 1.5.0, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.10.0, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.4.0, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.4.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for GDAL==2.4.0
```

If I understand this correctly, this meant, it downloaded GDAL-2.4.0,then say its couldnt find a version that sastisfied GDAL==2.4.0 (then show me a list with GDAL 2.4.0 on it)

I've been stuck on this issue so long now, so any help would be appriciated!!

Comment: The apls package depends on a specific old version of gdal. I'd suggest you contact the package author about that.

Comment: I'm a little shy about that. But i'm also getting desperate, so i guess i'll give that a try.